# HTML downloads page rather than content

Tags: html, vue.js, download

I have been working on my website and when I tried to implement a download page, it didn't seem to work

```html
<a href="data.json" download="data.json">Download as JSON file</a>
```

Instead of downloading `data.json`, it downloaded the HTML download page. When I opened the file, rather than

```
{
"key":"value"
}
```

I found the HTML contents! How can I solve this?

### Things I tried

- Check for any spelling mistakes - none found
- Checking syntax of entire page

### Possible things that *might* affect whats going on

- I am using Vue.js Server Side Rendering

Comment: Can you verify that `data.json` actualy exists at that URL? (Try entering the URL directly in the address bar)

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

This is wrong. Keeping the answer for reference. See @tony19's comment.

---

The download attribute takes no argument, try

```
<a href="data.json" download>Download as JSON file</a>
```

Comment: That's not actually true. The `download` value specifies a default filename to use on the target system.

Answer (score 1):

No need to specify the argument in Download.
Try With only Download.